# CollectionViewSource CurrentChanged not triggering

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I wonder if I am doing something wrong? My CurrentChanged does not seem to trigger. It only triggers on application start

```
ListItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
ListItems.Add("hello");
ListItems.Add("world");
ListItems.Add("foo");
ListItems.Add("bar");
ListItems.Add("baz");
viewSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListItems);
viewSource.CurrentChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)viewSource.CurrentItem);
};
```

Comment: This looks fine to me, where do you change the list?

Comment: I found out the problem. I must set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh I found out the problem. I must set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`